# Adding a Flip Side View controller to a class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to add a Flipside View controller to an existing view in a project. I dragged a regular view view controller and named the seugue to be popover. This is the difinition of the header of my FlipSideView Controller

```
@class InfoViewController;

@protocol InfoViewControllerDelegate

- (void)infoViewControllerDidFinish:(InfoViewController *)controller;

@end

@interface InfoViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <InfoViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;

@end
```

I implemented the following methods method on the Main View Controller to affect the toggle

```
- (void)infoViewControllerDidFinish:(InfoViewController *)controller
{
    [self.infoPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    self.infoPopoverController = nil;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showAlternate"]) {
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
        UIPopoverController *popoverController = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];
        self.infoPopoverController = popoverController;
        popoverController.delegate = self;
    }
}

- (IBAction)togglePopover:(id)sender
{
    if (self.infoPopoverController) {
        [self.infoPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        self.infoPopoverController = nil;
    } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showAlternate" sender:sender];
    }
}
```

This is the header of my MainViewController

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "InfoViewController.h"

@interface LandingViewController : UIViewController <InfoViewControllerDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *infoPopoverController;

@end
```

Thing is nothing happens, the popover doesn't come through.Is there an issue with multiple segues on the same ViewController. Since I already have a automatic segue being triggered by a button on the same ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue, I wasn't triggering the segue from the button. Well the documentation says that for a FlipSideView the segue is not triggered by the button, thus I was dragging and dropping from one view controller to the other and hooking up the toggle method. 
Once I hooked up the segue with the button, everything seems to be working fine.